# iOS6 app crashing in the background. How to decode the crash log?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, background, crash

My app keeps crashing in the background. I do have some background tasks running that connect to a webservice. I have tried making those synchronous as well as asynchronous calls. Nothing seems to help. The maddening part is the crash log gives me no indication what exactly causes the crash. Apart from the fact that I am not ending my background task properly or within 600 seconds. How does the backtrace tell me where in my app and what thread caused the crash?

I am also not sure if the crash is because when the app was already in the background and then i called the webservice and it never returned (even though i am using synchronous right now) or is it because I was connecting to the webservice when the app went to the background and that is what is causing the crash.

I have read all SO posts regarding this. Also it never breaks on the simulator with app in the background and also with me turing off the network or turning it back on. Help please?

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         MyApp [6705]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/162096EB-66CC-46DB-916F-98ED5888CA26/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-03-25 16:38:14.384 -0500
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.2 (10B146)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
MyApp[6705] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x1d569690> identifier: UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask process: MyApp[6705] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:6705 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep ,
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x1d56abb0> identifier: UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask process: MyApp[6705] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:6705 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep ,
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x1d56b580> identifier: UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask process: MyApp[6705] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:6705 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep 
)}

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 58.900 (user 58.900, system 0.000), 5% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 5.047, 0% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a599eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a59a048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32364040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32362d5a __CFRunLoopRun + 810
4   CoreFoundation                  0x322d5eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x322d5d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   GraphicsServices                0x35eac2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
7   UIKit                           0x341eb2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
8   MyApp                       0x0006ff20 main (main.m:14)
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x3a4e3b1c start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a59a648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a4ca974 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a4ca654 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 32

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a599eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a59a048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32364040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32362d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x322d5eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x322d5d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x382df500 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a50330e _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a5031d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a599eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a59a048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32364040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32362d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x322d5eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x322d5d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x32c223d0 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304
7   Foundation                      0x32ca5e80 __NSThread__main__ + 968
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a50330e _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a5031d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a5aa594 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x323681f2 __CFSocketManager + 674
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a50330e _pthread_start + 306
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a5031d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  AQClient
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a599eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a59a048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32364040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32362d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x322d5eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x322d5d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   AudioToolbox                    0x31db76fe GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 134
7   AudioToolbox                    0x31d98882 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 294
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a50330e _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a5031d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a5aa08c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a4fbd2a _pthread_cond_wait + 642
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a4fbaa0 pthread_cond_timedwait + 40
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x362a2c70 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 104
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x363b4552 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 78
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x363c6fa8 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 12
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a50330e _pthread_start + 306
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a5031d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a5aa08c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a4fbd2a _pthread_cond_wait + 642
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a505f14 pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x36347f3c JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 144
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x36347e7c JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 140
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x363c6fa8 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 12
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a50330e _pthread_start + 306
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a5031d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a5aad98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a4f8cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a4f8a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a4f88a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a5aad98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a4f8cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a4f8a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a4f88a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a5aad98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a4f8cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a4f8a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a4f88a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a5aad98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a4f8cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a4f8a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a4f88a0 start_wqthread + 4

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1

Binary Images:
   0x6e000 -    0xd0fff +MyApp armv7  <12ba291b4714399cb208b80115eeabbe> /var/mobile/Applications/162096EB-66CC-46DB-916F-98ED5888CA26/MyApp.app/MyApp
0x2fe50000 - 0x2fe70fff  dyld armv7  <454baf45f9a831aa88e1ea4447c58d4e> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3139d000 - 0x314a6fff  IMGSGX543GLDriver armv7  <609224802968399ca46e3b0db6af8a08> /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX543GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX543GLDriver
0x314b0000 - 0x31596fff  AVFoundation armv7  <320761e836883aeabf3cb5c53edb636d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x31597000 - 0x31597fff  Accelerate armv7  <b68ff92e404931f3bcb6361720f77724> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x31598000 - 0x316d6fff  vImage armv7  <30522b92940d3dd184c8e46780594048> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x316d7000 - 0x317bafff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <d8edada1cea133458ca779e34a3a7f88> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x317bb000 - 0x31a70fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <9e08aead79d13043bab622402a270fba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x31a71000 - 0x31acafff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <09e2a5e3e9203950890ba57592523132> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x31acb000 - 0x31adcfff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <7b7d4ccc9f2b364cb0da4251e745545d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x31add000 - 0x31addfff  vecLib armv7  <a7751c047dcc35ba8885212e1938b93f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31ade000 - 0x31aeffff  Accounts armv7  <ea2de358b6cc3baab27d6ab809c31e39> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x31af1000 - 0x31b55fff  AddressBook armv7  <3001f4364f9d3222b2a500a9f6897af8> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x31c20000 - 0x31d5afff  AudioCodecs armv7  <e5fa86b788b133178bb2b64d6a817708> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioCodecs
0x31d5b000 - 0x31fe3fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <bb11489c87e93a3b8c26aa995a2fdec9> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x31fe4000 - 0x320a9fff  CFNetwork armv7  <4771a5e4f9b83bceb252f0f3d166aaca> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x320aa000 - 0x32100fff  CoreAudio armv7  <5d534dbf76ff30f4a628f25f56c5f26a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x32114000 - 0x322ccfff  CoreData armv7  <3930f672c76535a2abb768ee59958fa7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x322cd000 - 0x323fffff  CoreFoundation armv7  <fcb8d4e838543bcb9a52c9f232b8b4eb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x32400000 - 0x32538fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <81e213f810a034d4ba411f9b505da2a6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x3253a000 - 0x32575fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <a5d20b80ab1532d8831027a66d2d9eb5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x32759000 - 0x32774fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ec1487f9bdb93597a3f8d434406ad9bf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x32775000 - 0x3282afff  CoreImage armv7  <6ae4ae2461313e3f84c6a8102d5b1b0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x3282b000 - 0x32883fff  CoreLocation armv7  <4107e94cdf043d6089e99cbd30631b07> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x328b8000 - 0x3291dfff  CoreMedia armv7  <8592bdc268b83b8886acfc1fdab649ed> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3291e000 - 0x329a6fff  CoreMotion armv7  <908cc54aecf5318e9719c4c9d70ef2e8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x329a7000 - 0x329fdfff  CoreTelephony armv7  <c5a2e59bb15d35b8a8e356e129b78b5e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x329fe000 - 0x32a60fff  CoreText armv7  <e135debbc8f937299f4986fc3e9459e3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x32a61000 - 0x32a70fff  CoreVideo armv7  <00f18bb26e663da9ae251a6ec36a19ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x32bf5000 - 0x32db8fff  Foundation armv7  <0179934581d13346aa7583165108b95c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x32f73000 - 0x32fbcfff  IOKit armv7  <a98ba9fefc7333e4a5a9169198848c62> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x32fbd000 - 0x33195fff  ImageIO armv7  <b5ce84bb074d3de4b07b55da9fd8bfd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x33196000 - 0x3320efff  MapKit armv7  <5c9f761b48a7381b818e253b56fc252f> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x333aa000 - 0x33624fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <ed439fc5c9a03f8b9fae43af33de8a57> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x336ac000 - 0x33705fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <77da8a9e7f813f5baf37eaa4a87fae84> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x33732000 - 0x337f3fff  GLEngine armv7  <b3fd8a93778b317fab8630340a2d741b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x337f4000 - 0x337fbfff  OpenGLES armv7  <f2ede6b206f336de82cc38619692e762> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x337fd000 - 0x337fdfff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <2506af1c983f3f09ac69aca44f67e863> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x337fe000 - 0x33800fff  libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7  <761c0f0e263c3d39adbb5bf789cedde1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x33801000 - 0x33803fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <af6ff28dce6031baaa850ccc79e5699b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x33804000 - 0x33808fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a6ac1673a088379aa512ba5cac301f5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33809000 - 0x33846fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <b8b8f3a1bfd0345e86aa0c2952534949> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x33847000 - 0x3396cfff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <0b3cb1b9a5003c4a975ec268cabca3fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x33f41000 - 0x34056fff  QuartzCore armv7  <c086b6e6cd9d341399bcc3675c82f1fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x340a5000 - 0x340d3fff  Security armv7  <fbc24f15bd9e37539cdd6e3576bde938> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x34142000 - 0x34151fff  StoreKit armv7  <e63a14831d2d315ba5cf654102d67f8c> /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit
0x34152000 - 0x34191fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <410d69b356e533d6a1d538cf33059634> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x34194000 - 0x346e8fff  UIKit armv7  <e138ca6a809b399691d933dd3d58d00e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x346e9000 - 0x34727fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <d2e8067306d9346ab4a448f10f336894> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x34728000 - 0x3473efff  iAd armv7  <e64ed3a1472d368e878a38e46803c73e> /System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework/iAd
0x34964000 - 0x34969fff  AITTarget armv7  <a06d2cb1f2c434fb8fcb57871a3075d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AITTarget.framework/AITTarget
0x349bd000 - 0x349c9fff  AccountSettings armv7  <8db45acc4d3d3017af10fa5ee82c2306> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x34a15000 - 0x34a18fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <a2170ad876f13ef1b944547913d05af2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x34b15000 - 0x34e21fff  Altitude armv7  <d507155292c8341395d2cbde05ae448d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Altitude.framework/Altitude
0x34e44000 - 0x34e7ffff  AppSupport armv7  <921794b7d82a3558a0eb860979be199c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x34ef2000 - 0x34efbfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <de7ca29cd47433cd8eca9c04102f5508> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x34efc000 - 0x34f14fff  AssistantServices armv7  <fdec07136e153720bc82f5fae4de5f77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x34f2a000 - 0x34f41fff  BackBoardServices armv7  <585cc62d83c530ee82988de940c1e161> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x34f4b000 - 0x34f6ffff  Bom armv7  <b5315d733e123a0781683efdc734064b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x34fef000 - 0x34ff6fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <a4f4b86cc84839f78ff746f013bcee6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x34ff7000 - 0x350c1fff  Celestial armv7  <a688df527b65382da586ebc87f28c061> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x351a5000 - 0x351aafff  CommonUtilities armv7  <f8fea9ee6ca236b0a7fa6c00eb8a0d24> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x352b1000 - 0x352dafff  CoreHandwriting armv7  <560667170b94358a8c7c72fd5b4a5a3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreHandwriting.framework/CoreHandwriting
0x35452000 - 0x3546ffff  CoreServicesInternal armv7  <09bda41ea1d935148d18c07a7102ede5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x35470000 - 0x35471fff  CoreSurface armv7  <6065f7e040e93d6ea2837e929592cc30> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x354de000 - 0x354e3fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <03ee46e3ca3f3920a7174e62096723fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x356b5000 - 0x356c7fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <b9423867a9ef303b87d2e1eac1712957> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x356db000 - 0x356f0fff  DataDetectorsCore armv7  <58352df07a0139de878e5e275e27ab52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x356f2000 - 0x35705fff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  <331c11e50793340f9ce758435c9420ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x35706000 - 0x35707fff  DataMigration armv7  <5903e08348b83f119022cbbf83ad100a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3570a000 - 0x35723fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <84669055e3e63d6ab56b8fe7b0476aaa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x3572b000 - 0x35743fff  EAP8021X armv7  <82a73adcf1db3d2f9e57cd22f71e44c9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x35758000 - 0x35795fff  FTServices armv7  <89c066d12a6031038a9b8c61221abc0a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x35796000 - 0x35ba9fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <43de0b31da3b39e4acf85ec2c8d5c65c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x35bf6000 - 0x35bfbfff  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib armv7  <4366fa0d1a0938a794bd8346e286d6f8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/libGPUSupportMercury.dylib
0x35da1000 - 0x35dadfff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d77ad2367fff37d485480aa39df7d325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x35dae000 - 0x35ea6fff  GeoServices armv7  <206a365f6bfe3278a9aecc1601015c7d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x35ea7000 - 0x35eb2fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <d4b7fd6509753bff9525fef374ddc359> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x35ff5000 - 0x3605efff  IMAVCore armv7  <7cf5c5830730339484703ca3a03a9e2d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMAVCore.framework/IMAVCore
0x3605f000 - 0x360d7fff  IMCore armv7  <d5f1d98ec53d3acbb51b116e93923d9c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x3619e000 - 0x361eafff  IMFoundation armv7  <797535fc363c3f818bcd1424251393bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x361f1000 - 0x361f2fff  IOAccelerator armv7  <9655464326203d258d3d0fc7e94651e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x361f3000 - 0x361f8fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <f38c374982a931d5a47458dd3c34ac59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x361f9000 - 0x361fdfff  IOSurface armv7  <a55bf03c35de3fd9b56dce82083c3d10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x36242000 - 0x36246fff  IncomingCallFilter armv7  <1b921222496e3006bf6d1f66456ab2bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IncomingCallFilter.framework/IncomingCallFilter
0x36247000 - 0x363edfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <a5780997f4b738659172f40877c9a7d9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x364b9000 - 0x36511fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <44bbb2ba85c8320bb9e73c654b90f8c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x36512000 - 0x36517fff  Marco armv7  <da45fc9b228b3d1fad95e03071441585> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x36528000 - 0x3659efff  MediaControlSender armv7  <9fb205b64b5333a495ac61c149e0304b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x366e8000 - 0x36715fff  MobileAsset armv7  <3a9e6258ae1230f5b12f1638b09cb974> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x3675a000 - 0x3675dfff  MobileInstallation armv7  <c63e4b1ae40635cd9c6a7de851c80d10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x3675e000 - 0x36764fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <35882c57076334aeb0641969a9b69ff3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x367c1000 - 0x367c4fff  MobileSystemServices armv7  <10b4eee2739c353183ac2cfe4e39a443> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x367dc000 - 0x367e5fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <bb4efbe3c7273c0fb534f12789756089> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x36975000 - 0x36977fff  OAuth armv7  <575df12a2f2436af92e31494c3b74465> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x370b1000 - 0x370d6fff  OpenCL armv7  <5bf059a9deb632678d70099f14f51b82> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x37437000 - 0x37454fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <c773b3dc885832f8a916de67f24f9f92> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x376ea000 - 0x37712fff  PrintKit armv7  <3f0b9c58a458358eb506858e8ff9e1fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x37713000 - 0x37787fff  ProofReader armv7  <9cb25467554637bcb268ba30527d3c0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x37788000 - 0x37790fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <d1f2888d5e5a39cca6a6179a35c86770> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x377ad000 - 0x37805fff  SAObjects armv7  <e00a21cdda433d8788f5878d2b1f90d3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SAObjects.framework/SAObjects
0x378cc000 - 0x378ddfff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <e2571f80a0ad3dc580c69794457bd887> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x3793f000 - 0x37a1afff  StoreServices armv7  <6d45f42eff2736d18cdd81af0473dd5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x37a68000 - 0x37a6afff  TCC armv7  <d5bef30a5bda315194173b862975f9fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x37a89000 - 0x37a96fff  TelephonyUtilities armv7  <803d7a92439238ee942086999c481eb6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x37a97000 - 0x37ebbfff  TextInput armv7  <d54d5ca42b503f26ab45e5efd4b87135> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x37f19000 - 0x37fb9fff  UIFoundation armv7  <9a464526e26634bc834537e5ac3abf1f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x37fd8000 - 0x3814efff  VectorKit armv7  <1f5d7d9b24cf379bb3dade61bbf7b3a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VectorKit.framework/VectorKit
0x38287000 - 0x3829dfff  VoiceServices armv7  <02e2faf1aceb3d2c94ad4528c7a23837> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
0x382b5000 - 0x382d4fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <77b65bc9c87b367ebea9a5b7984b13a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x382d5000 - 0x38c04fff  WebCore armv7  <ce52fd40ccc236c4b86c020beabb1bb0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x38c05000 - 0x38ce2fff  WebKit armv7  <dee20c7689bc3e029172b488d8c5f772> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x38d8d000 - 0x38d94fff  XPCObjects armv7  <723fe314ab95381cbfa69a0000005692> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x3934a000 - 0x39364fff  TextInput_zh armv7  <9955ec20ab1a3656b0dbda157637199a> /System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_zh.bundle/TextInput_zh
0x39921000 - 0x39927fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <f40705b5e9c43ce3b1f185fe690b9ac8> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x39928000 - 0x3993efff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <5a8a3d18a1ff3c97bd773705fef2d81c> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x39956000 - 0x39962fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <ea41737238273d73b173ec09358d7b62> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x39974000 - 0x39974fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <7aeeab280f7e361e9986d962d0fa5281> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x39a96000 - 0x39aa2fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <3870b1c8b1783b788bd51da1a04eae6e> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x39aa3000 - 0x39aacfff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <b04d27fa0f2d31d8bd0745f8aa0d7f67> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x39aad000 - 0x39af7fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <ceb9fb64fb203d3a94063a9db6590ca4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x39af8000 - 0x39b0bfff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <4b8520bc534231ae97ce146e076bc7bf> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x39b3c000 - 0x39c29fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <ac23bb84e91e35418c9a2fb4792658b2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x39c2a000 - 0x39d73fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <da9d04cc6f6d3825aa52636342ef1e04> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x39d7b000 - 0x39d7bfff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <a10d8f96815d35e0a1d2c7b998a941f3> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x39d7e000 - 0x39d85fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <996afbc31d8b3f2a907be2427509a4c8> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x39d86000 - 0x39d9bfff  liblzma.5.dylib armv7  <4a1f38cbee783a9ea6de94af25d45cc1> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x39ec2000 - 0x3a065fff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <0747e596e9983bd6a76cf8349da325e4> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x3a066000 - 0x3a07bfff  libmis.dylib armv7  <7502589f14733beb963c542fa40438c8> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x3a0a4000 - 0x3a1a2fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <79e5d714945834e4b2587abfc6c7269c> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3a266000 - 0x3a27bfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <3ee61a04a99b322e97e179bc03c46cf1> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3a2a0000 - 0x3a325fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <cbefd01867b93d2a869a534825a1414c> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3a326000 - 0x3a371fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <e3154b06ac5d360c948111abfb2bc339> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3a372000 - 0x3a398fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <c43990ee3a5e389aacf288c3615a50dc>
```

....
Ommited for brevity.

Comment: Try [Crashlytics](http://crashlytics.com), this will collect all crash logs include background thread.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the following part in your log:

```
Application Specific Information:
MyApp[6705] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x1d569690> identifier: UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask process: MyApp[6705] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:6705 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep ,
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x1d56abb0> identifier: UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask process: MyApp[6705] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:6705 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep ,
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x1d56b580> identifier: UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask process: MyApp[6705] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:6705 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep 
)}
```

It appears to be that you are calling `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` without the corresponding `endBackgroundTask:` call.

Find out more about `endBackgroundTask` in the following [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I updated my question with how i call the background service. I do call endbackgroundtask. And I use the Console App from itunes to also confirm i get the NSlog updates saying how i call and end my tasks with the task id.

Comment: @DurgaDash I'm not saying you're not, but the crash log says there's a problem in that area

Comment: Have you tried using the link conditioner, with lossy network, and  adjust the packet drops so that whatever task is accomplished never finishes in 600 sec? Also try 100% loss for a few seconds while there is traffic, so that the ip stack restart the connection. This might help you replicate the problem.

Comment: I used to connect to the webservice using asynchronous now I have switched to synchronous with timeout on NSURLRequest set to 15 seconds. And yes i have tried the link conditioner have not been able to replicate the crash. it always happens when i am not looking :)

Answer (score 0):

### get the crash log to Xcode and symbolicate it there

how? one way (of the top of my head .... it might not be ideal)

1. build your app as an archive and keep it in the organizer
2. install that archived version on the device
3. let it crash
4. connect your phone and go to Xcode organizer, devices, crash reports
5. click on re-symbolicate and it uses the app you archived to make it readable

Comment: but you don't really crash. you are killed by the os